# Delete books from the sony erearder TRS1?

Tags: sony-prs-t1

I have a Sony Ereader TRS 1 and I want to delete books from my library on the pc. It only lets me delete books from the "All Available Books" drop down menu - NOT from the "Purchased from the Store" menu. I know how to delete books from my reader, but I have titles that I don't want anymore taking up space on my computer.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: With a 32Gb SD card costing USD 10 why would you worry about a few megabytes of bought books sitting on your machine?

Comment: @Anthon Yes?  I have the T2, and at 3,000 odd books, it's (a) very slow to update the library, and (b) very difficult to search the bookshelves.  I really need a _smaller_ SD card :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to go to the Kobo store and move  the books from your Library to Archive (view books in the library, click on  the "..." below the book image in the cover view, or in the action column of the list view, and select "Move to Archive").